# How can I run script that was added to the page with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing <script> elements inserted with .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml)
>   [Dynamically Inserting <script> tags into HTML on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114035/dynamically-inserting-script-tags-into-html-on-page-load)

What I mean is that if I do .innerHTML write that contains

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // embedded code here </script>
```

The embedded code does not run and neither does the linked to code.  It is "dead".

Is there a way to manually trigger it?

Comment: What about errors in javascript console?

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamically Inserting <script> tags into HTML on Page Load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114035/dynamically-inserting-script-tags-into-html-on-page-load) or [How Do I Load a JavaScript File Dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically) or [How to Load JavaScript Dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943004/how-to-load-javascript-dynamically) or [Load JavaScript Dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293344/load-javascript-dynamically) or …

Comment: How are these tags being added?

Comment: @Phrogz, Quentin, this is 3 different answers to one problem..this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Rocket - via .innerHTML write...I get the data from and ajax response.

Comment: http://24ways.org/2005/have-your-dom-and-script-it-too... this way is a hack that uses a downloaded images onload property, which apparently fires when written to the .innerHTML, to run some script

Comment: Got to go with it...as is about 1 line of code instead of 35 for the other "solutions"...just use like a 1 byte image on your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the javascript to the head tag, 
i.e

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://www.somedomain.com/somescript.js';
head.appendChild(newScript);
```

(this is a quite common thing, but i copied the code from here: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS )

---

*on a side note:* 
if you use jQuery you will be tempted to write the following:

```
<script>
    [....]
    $( "head" ).append( "<script src='myScript.js'></script>" ); 
    [....]
</script>
```

note that this doesn't work because the javascript parser will see the first `</script>` and stop parsing right there.

Comment: So I take it that appending ( appendChild ) it is different from doing a .innerHTML write for some reason?

Comment: i think it's about adding to the head, not how to add it ... if you open up the javascript console on a page with jquery and try you can see that both these work: ```$("head").html("<script>alert('x');</script>")```  as well as $("head").append("<script>alert('x');</script>")